# Find and update specific object in array of objects in javascript - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects of books like following:

[image]

I have an update statement where I can update the state of a specific book.
The values that I have available are id (like "IOejDAAAQBAJ") and what the new value of the shelf has to be.

How do I select the specific object with that ID and update that objects value of shelf?

The end result has to be the exact same array only with that one object with adjusted shelf value.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, please post the code, even if it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop on objects and return the `shelf` property with the new value if the `id` is matching.

```js
arr = [{
  'id': '1',
  'shelf': 'wantToRead'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'shelf': 'wantToRead'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'shelf': 'wantToRead'
}];
arr.forEach(function(elt) {
  return (elt.id === '2') ? elt.shelf = "new value" : null;
})
console.log(arr);
```